# How can I change the font size of the scaling factor on y axis in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm reading in time series data and I want to make an aggregate plot using matplotlib. I managed to set appropriate font sizes for the axis titles and labels. However, I could not find the function that would allow me to change the font size of the y axis scaling factor.

```py
# Only updates the size of the ticks
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
```

I expected the font size of the scaling factor (shown in the top left) will update as I update the font size of the labels (ticks).

Comment: can you paste a picture of what is shown on top left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaling factor on the y-axis you are referring to is called `offsetText`. To change its properties, you need to access it via the axis instance of your figure.

---

**Minimal complete answer**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2/10**7
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)

ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(25)
plt.show()
```

[image]